# Prevent bots from registering in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I noticed in my e-shop that there were a couple of mysterious customers that were signing up and I decided to stop it. The way I chose to do it was to create an extra field in the sign up page in

> app/design/frontend/xlcloset/deafault/template/officience/customerattributeform/register.phtml

Its style would be **style="display:none"** so that it would be not visible. This form sends tits data with the **$this->getPostActionUrl()**. So the concept would be to check if the field is filled and if yes, stop the execution of the program (like die(); ). I found the **getFormData()** function which is:

```
  public function getFormData()
{    

    $data = $this->getData('form_data');
    $china = $data['firstname'];      

    if (is_null($data)) {          
        $formData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerFormData(true);             
        $data = new Varien_Object();          
        if ($formData) {                                
            $data->addData($formData);
            $data->setCustomerData(1); 
        }
        if (isset($data['region_id'])) {
            $data['region_id'] = (int)$data['region_id'];                  
        }            
        $variable = $this->setData('form_data', $data);           

    }    

    return $data;
}
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to perform the check in this method in order to check if the hidden field is filled. Thank you for the help in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

OK, for this approach, I was looking in the wrong file. The right one was in the AccountController.php file and the **createPostAction()** in which I had to perform the test like:

```
if (!empty($_POST['name'])){
         $this->_redirect('*/*/');    
         return;
    }
```